# How to get the deleted category id?

Tags: categories

I want to do some action at the time of deleting a category using that category id. Is it possible to get the category id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `delete_category` action, which passes category id as an argument:

```
function my_category_delete_function( $id ){
    // do something with category $id
}
add_action( 'delete_category', 'my_category_delete_function', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work and similarly it's possible to get the slug of the deleted category?